# Secret link to get updates for Acrobat Professional 8.0?

Tags: windows-7, adobe-acrobat

**Finding the Acrobat Pro 8.0 Updates ... Anywhere?** 
As best I can tell, Adobe has removed all updates for Acrobat Professional 8.

This link -- http://www.adobe.com/downloads/updates.html -- goes to their product update page.From there I went to http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/product.jsp?product=1&platform=Windows and poked around the obvious and not-so-obvious choices and keep coming up empty.

Assuming it really is impossible to get the 8.0 updates from the Adobe site, does anyone know a truly trustworthy source for getting the updates?

**Background.**
I've been running Windows 7 and Acrobat 8.0 for several years. Last month I had to scrub my system to rid of a virus. Everything is now re-loaded, but I need the updates for Acrobat 8.0 so that I can take care of a few pesky problems like being able to print to PDF from Quicken 99. Or to right-click from the desktop to combine PDFs into a single file.

It was all working before I had to scrub, so I know it's possible to get 64 bit and 32 bit to play nicely together.

Normally I save the update exe files for situations exactly like this, i.e., when the vendor removes the files you need to keep running a legacy program. For some dumb reason, I failed to do it for Acrobat Professional 8.0, and though I'm usually pretty handy with web searches to dig up otherwise elusive stuff, this time I'm getting nowhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you still have a serial key for it, this installs version 8.1.0:

https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/acrobat-8-9-product-downloads.html

Also available on their ftp site:

ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/acrobat/win/8.x/

Latest update (8.3.1):

ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/acrobat/win/8.x/8.3.1/misc/

Comment: Wow! What search terms did you use to find the download(s) and the alternate paths?

Comment: I'm now "working through" your candidate downloads (thank you TheKB!). 

The AcroPro80_efg.exe program incorrectly rejects my serial number (I know my number is valid because I triple-checked it in my Adobe account.) 

The rejected serial number may have something to do with a CS3 problem, of which there are steps to correct. But before I try that, I'm trying your other two solutions (at the ftp sites). 

So far those are failing due to alleged Windows Installer problems.

Arrrghhh. So I'll keep at it for awhile. When/if the magic happens, I'll report back.

Comment: @RJo I googled "adobe ftp" (: Try updating to acrobat 8.1 first and then trying?

Comment: To TheKB ... I'd give you a vote but don't have the reputation to do it yet.

Comment: I just had a "whack" on the side of my head that TheKB exactly answered my question. The tangential question and answer -- how to successfully install -- is the one I wrote up elsewhere in this thread. And I could not have done it without TheKBs help.

Comment: Note that the installer from the [first link](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/acrobat-8-9-product-downloads.html) is a version that requires downloading an e-license from Adobe, which probably means you can't install it on another computer until you return the e-license on the first computer.  That's assuming you can even download the installer - a couple of my computers got a Java error when trying to download it.

Answer (score 3):

OK -- Success! I can now print to PDF from Quicken 99, and I can right-click from the desktop to combine multiple PDFs into a single PDF.

(Thank you to TheKB for providing trail to update files.) (Hmmm ... I am guessing that TheKB is your handle for "The Knowledge Base" -- is that a good guess?)

Here's a summary of what I had to do. It was time-consuming, and I encountered surprise malware. Perhaps my summary will help save time for others.

**Assumption**: You are starting from Acrobat Professional 8.0 and you want the English update.

1. Use the downloads at ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/acrobat/win/8.x/ because that is where you will find the complete list of all updates (patches).
2. Download all of the patches before you begin installing. It will save you time because you have to reboot after almost every patch. You do **not** need all of the files offered. You **do** need the file(s) for English. See next step.
3. Your first download is AcrobatUpd810_efgj_incr.msp (Note: the "efgj" means English-French-German-Japanese.)
4. Your subsequent downloads are all AcrobatUpdNNN_all_incr.msp where NNN = the update number. For example: 811, 812, 813, etc. (***Tip***: Open two or more browser windows so you can download more than one at a time.)
5. Most of the updates are **not** chained and you **may** have to reboot after almost every install, as I did.
6. See below for the list of files I installed. Although a few had chained updates, you should download every one rather than rely on my findings. I discovered which ones were chained by working backwards from 831 to 830 etc. Also see below for an explanation of the malware.

**Installed Files: AcrobatUpdNNN_...**

810_efgi_incr.msp
811_all_incr.msp
812
813
816 (includes 814 and 815)
817 (this is the final 81N update)
820
822 (includes 821) 
823
825 (includes 824)
826 (this is the final 82N update)
830
831 (this is the final 83N update)

**Raptr Malware Incident**
I installed 823 and rebooted. Upon reboot, I was greeted with a Raptr gaming login screen. I am **not** a gamer in any form and would never knowingly install a game. So I used my iPad to research this one (wanting to avoid an internet connection with my PC until I knew what I was dealing with).

I found out that the game was installed by AMD and that it has some interaction with Adobe CS.

I have no idea what actually triggered the Raptr login screen. I.e., was it something that downloaded with the 823 update? Was it something lurking in AMD that woke up when I rebooted?

Whatever ... I couldn't get rid of it fast enough. I used Programs > Uninstall and then searched for (and found and deleted) a dozen other raptr files on my system (the Windows Uninstall did not get rid of everything by itself).

**Closing**
I know this was a long post. And I do hope that people viewing this post find value in it.

Comment: Yes, TheKB is shorthand for the knowledge base. Glad I could help. Raptr is owned by amd. It automatically installs with the amd driver, which is probably why you have it.

Comment: In [my experience](http://superuser.com/a/1042678/115033) (and supported by Adobe forum MVPs), it is safe to install all of the updates without rebooting until the very end.  Just click on "No" each time the system prompts you to reboot after installing one of the updates, and continue with the installation of the next update.  It will save a ton of time.

Comment: Would be great to always be able to rely on how things are advertised to work. But 'tis not so, and that's why StackExchange is such a fantastic resource.