# Can I install all Adobe updates and just reboot at the end?

Tags: windows, updates, adobe-acrobat

I found a [post](https://superuser.com/a/859426/115033) detailing how to upgrade Adobe Acrobat Pro 8.0.0 to 8.3.1.  It involves downloading 13 different patches, and it says you have to reboot after installing each patch.

I imagine that each patch will prompt you to reboot Windows after it is installed, but do you really need to reboot between each patch?

Could I just install all 13 patches (from oldest to most recent), and then reboot just one time at the end?  Or does Windows put on lock on the patched files, so that if I tried to install a subsequent patch without rebooting, it would fail?

Comment: What does Adobe say? :)

Comment: You could always uninstall your current version of Acrobat, then download, the current version of it.  This avoids installing patches.

Comment: @Ramhound I am unaware of any full download for version 8.3.1.

Comment: I had no problem downloading the current version of Adobe XI, and Adobe 9 in the past skipping the the patches that were eventually released, after the original baseline version was released. I don't have a license to Adobe Acrobat 8 but I can't see how that version would be any different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a couple posts<sup>([1](https://forums.adobe.com/message/7052950#7052950), [2](https://forums.adobe.com/message/7987082#7987082))</sup> from Adobe forum MVPs who said that you can install all the updates and just reboot once at the end.  I did that and it seemed to work.